# PHP 7 debugger settings in eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt, php-7

I've changed the version of php from 5.6 to the new version: 7.0.
So far, everything works fine; but some new features of php 7 are not recognized by the debugger. For example the line:

```
$flag = $params['flag'] ?? true;
```

is marked by the debugger - symbol `?` not recognized, but when I run the program it is working correctly!

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Its because your PHP version is updated from `5.6` to `7.0` and not your `IDE` and moreover you can also check it over online PHP editor like as over [here](https://3v4l.org/31NrF)

Comment: How can I configure Eclipse to work with php 7 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version of PDT released with Eclipse Mars supports all major PHP 7 features. Your example is about Null Coalesce Operator (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=466966) and it is ready to use with PDT.

To remove error in PHP editor go to your project preferences (context menu in PHP Explorer) and choose PHP -> Interpreter and change it to PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use php in eclipse, PDT and PDT mylyn must be installed.
PDT (PHP development tool) - is the PHP IDE project delivers a PHP Integrated Development Environment framework for the Eclipse platform. PDT is not fully supports php7 yet, see: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465701

Usualy new vertion of PDT is released with new vertion of eclipse. So probably PDT for the next vertion Mars (Eclipse 4.5) will fully support php7.